# ActiveMQ Queue : Selectors and Exclusive consumer

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to use a queue with multiple subscribers (each with a unique selector) along with setting the destination.consumer.exclusive flag to true. But when I post a message to this Queue, I see that the message is available with in the queue but none of the subscribers have picked it up in spite of it meeting one of the consumer's selector criteria.
I see the following details on the AMQ UI console:

- Number of pending messages - 1
- Number of consumers - 6
- Messages enqueued - 1
- Messages dequeued - 0

Although the number of messages pending on the queue is 1, none of the consumers have any "enqueues" on them in spite of the pnding mesage meeting the selection criteria.

Comment: If your selectors are all different, you already have your 'exclusivity' implemented that way. Did you try with destination.consumer.exclusive flag set to false ?

Comment: Setting the destination.consumer.exclusive to false did allow the messages to be picked up but I had to let go of the resiliency feature provided by AMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclusive consumers would override any selector in terms of Queue load balancing so use either one or the other.  Exclusive consumer is named that way for a reason, namely the consumer is the only one that can consume from the Queue until it goes offline.  It really doesn't make any sense to mix selectors and exclusive options in the first place.